# bash to zsh command not found

Tags: java, command, zsh

Hi I've just changed bash to zsh and I m tryin to run a simple java on my desktop with is HelloWorld.java

but when I run on terminal and on my desktop it doesn't see the java class and gives me the error

**command:**
`dede@Gokhan-MacBook-Pro desktop % /Users/dede/Desktop/HelloWorld.java`

it gives me this **error:**
`zsh: permission denied: /Users/dede/Desktop/HelloWorld.java`

or when I run **command** like this:
`dede@Gokhan-MacBook-Pro desktop % HelloWorld.java`

it gives me this **error**:
`zsh: command not found: HelloWorld.java`

thanks for helping

Comment: What command you using to try and run the program? You don't seem to be using `java` or `javac` or anything I'd expect

Comment: @DedeSezer : Technically speaking, in order to run a file (such as your `/Users/dede/Desktop/HelloWorld.java`, the file needs to have x-permissions, and the operating needs to know how the file has to be loaded and executed (this is usually derived from the first two bytes of the file, i.e. the _magic number_). If your file is just Java source, you can't execute it. You have to compile it first. This is not related to the shell, but to Java.

Comment: i hava java and javac in my mac

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a java program just by trying to execute a `.java` file. 
The `.java` file is a **text file** containing just source code and needs to be compiled first with `javac` :

```
javac  /Users/dede/Desktop/HelloWorld.java
```

then go to the dir storing the compiled `.class` file and run it with `java` command

```
cd  /Users/dede/Desktop/
java HelloWorld
```